# Парсинг входящих параметров args в Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть такая строка запуска:

```
java -jar smart-file-handler-cli -p -s xml \
    -o /path/result.log 'text for search' ./
```

Вопрос о аргументах приложения:

```
-p -s xml -o /path/result.log 'text for search' ./
```

Как их удобнее всего распарсить? При том, что после `-o`, это всё одно значение опционального аргумента.

Попробовал сделать [regex](https://regex101.com/r/x2FUke/1):

```
/((-[\w]) (.*)?) ((-[\w]) (.*)?)/g
```

Пробовал применить парсеры команды, такие как: commons cli, google options. Но все они не спарсили адекватно опцию `-o`.

Может доработать ругулярку? Или как можно еще?

Comment: лучше всего использовать готовые решения, например, Apache Common CLI  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Comment: @DaysLikeThis я вроде как описал что он не парсит всю команду.

Comment: Вариант получать на своей стороне значение для `-o` как `option.getValues()` и потом собирать единую строку из данного массива приемлем? Хотя, это, костыль, скорее всего

Comment: @Chubatiy проблема в том что он не записывает все что после пути вообще. то бишь эта часть `'text for search' ./` тупо пропадает.

Comment: @Tsyklop если параметр включает в себя разделители, их нужно объединять с помощью кавычек -o "/path/result.log 'text for search'"

Comment: @Tsyklop странно. У меня вот возвращает массив из трёх элементов (`[/path/result.log, text for search, ./]`). Юзаю commons cli

Comment: @Chubatiy можно код? пожалуйста

Comment: @Tsyklop привел в качестве ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Option option1 = Option
            .builder()
            .longOpt("p")
            .argName("p")
            .build();
    Option option2 = Option
            .builder()
            .longOpt("s")
            .argName("s")
            .hasArgs()
            .build();
    Option option3 = Option
            .builder()
            .longOpt("o")
            .argName("o")
            .hasArgs()
            .numberOfArgs(3)
            .build();
    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

    CommandLine parse = parser.parse(new Options().addOption(option1).addOption(option2).addOption(option3), args);

    for (Option o : parse.getOptions()) {
        System.out.println(o.getLongOpt() + " " +  Arrays.toString(o.getValues()));
    }
```

Т.е. потом склеить `o.getValues()` для вашего случая

Входные аргументы

> -p -s xml -o /path/result.log 'text for search' ./

Вывод работы программы

> p null s [xml] o [/path/result.log, text for search, ./]

Comment: а сам массив аргументов какой?

Comment: @Tsyklop вывод программы привел в пример

Comment: а изначально массив аргументов какой? Просто то что я привел в пример в первом посте, это условия. Их я менять не могу.

Comment: @Tsyklop как вы и писали в вопросе. Но я привел пример запуска

Comment: Вот это странно. У меня в `-o` входит только `/path/result.log`

Comment: А вы точно `o.getValues()` вызываете? А не `o.getValue()`? + версия commons-cli у меня 1.4

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76628/discussion-between-chubatiy-and-tsyklop).